Separation of variables method with $u(0,x)=5e^{x^2}-e^{-10x^2};x>0$

\begin{cases}
x\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}} + \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=0 \\
u(0,x)=5e^{x^2}-e^{-10x^2};x>0
\end{cases}

Writing $u(x,t)=X(x)U(t)$:
\begin{align*}
&xX(x)\Big(\frac{10te^{t^2}+20te^{-10t^2}}{X(0)}\Big) + X'(x)\frac{5e^{t^2}-e^{-10t^2}} {X(0)}=0  \\[7pt] \iff
&xX(x)\frac{10te^{t^2}+20te^{-10t^2}}{5e^{t^2}-e^{-10t^2}}+X'(x)=0  \\[9pt] \iff
&X(x)=\exp\Big(-{\frac{10te^{t^2}+20te^{-10t^2}}{5e^{t^2}-e^{-10t^2}}\frac{x^2}{2}}\Big)
\end{align*}
And now,  $ \large u(x,t)= \frac{e^{-{\frac{10te^{t^2}+20te^{-10t^2}}{5e^{t^2}-e^{-10t^2}}\frac{x^2}{2}}}(5e^{t^2}-e^{-10t^2})}{X(0)}$. Is this the final form of the problem's solution or is there any further simplification?
EDIT:
$$\begin{cases}
\langle (x,1)  ,\nabla u \rangle=0 \\
u(0,x)=5e^{x^2}-e^{-10x^2};x>0
\end{cases}$$
So, the curves with $(x,1)$ as tangent vectors have slope:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{x} \iff \frac{x^2(t)}{2}=t+c ; \; c \in \mathbb{R}$$
So,
$$\frac{d}{dt}u(t,\pm \sqrt{2(t+c)})=0$$
And $u$ is only a function of $x$ and by the boundary condition, $u(t,x)=k (5e^{x^2}-e^{-10x^2}); k \in \mathbb{R}$. Is this a correct conclusion?

Your solution for $X(x)$ also depends on $t$. Do you think it is correct?

@Gonçalo, how can I simplify the expression for $X(x)$?

You can't. The method of separation of variables doesn't work in this case. Do you know the method of characteristics?

I'm afraid that I don't know it yet

Time to learn: method of characteristics.

@Gonçalo, could it be that $u(t,x)=f(\frac{x^2}{2}-t)$? And then I should use the boundary condition, sure?

Your title and problem do not match

@JP, you found the general solution to the PDE. Now use the initial condition $f(x^2/2)=u(0,x)$ to determine $f$.

@Gonçalo, $f(x)=5e^{2x}-e^{-20x}$, is that so?

Yes, so $u(t,x)=f(x^2/2-t)=5e^{x^2-2t}-e^{-10x^2+20t}$.

This is a linear first-order PDE, so we can solve it using characteristic lines
$$
\dfrac{dt}{x}=\dfrac{dx}{1} \qquad \implies \qquad t=\dfrac12x^2+C.
$$
Thus, the general solution is $$
u(t,x)=f\big(t-\frac12x^2\big),
$$
where $f(\cdot)$ is an arbitrary function. Then, using the condition at $t=0$,
$$
u(0,x)=f\big(-\frac12x^2\big)=5e^{x^2}-e^{-10x^2}
$$
we infer that $f(\cdot)$ is the function $$
f(z)=5e^{-2z}-e^{20z}.
$$
Therefore, the solution is given by $$
u(t,x)=5e^{x^2-2t}-e^{20t-10x^2}.
$$
